# Avoiding unnecessary recomputation in singletons

Tags: c#, initialization, singleton

Consider the following C# singleton class and client of said class

```
class TheSingleton
{
    TheSingleton() { /* initialize properties x, y, z */ }
    public static TheSingleton Instance() { /* classic Singleton implementation */ }
    public void Refresh() { /* refreshes properties x, y, z */ }
}

class TheClient
{
    static void SomeWork()
    {
        /* ... does some updates that means that TheSingleton's properties have to be refreshed */
        TheSingleton.Instance().Refresh();
    }
}
```

Scenario 1

- calls are made to `TheSingleton.Instance()` which initializes x, y and z
- some time later `TheClient.SomeWork()` is called
- `TheSingleton.Instance().Refresh()` is called which refreshes x, y and z
- everything is cool

Scenario 2

- **no** calls are made to `TheSingleton.Instance()`
- `TheClient.SomeWork()` is called which calls `TheSingleton.Instance().Refresh();`
- `TheSingleton.Instance()` new's the `TheSingleton` and the `TheSingleton` constructor initializes x, y and z
- immediately after returning from `Instance()`, `SomeWork()` calls `Refresh()` which is a waste of processing since x, y and z have only just been initialized.
- everything is no longer cool

What are some **elegant** approaches for avoiding the re-computation of x, y and z in Scenario 2?

Thanks, Pete

Comment: you are basically looking for time based caching?

Comment: The elegant solution is to kill off your singleton "global variable" anti-pattern and return a `Tuple<xType, yType, zType>` from `SomeWork()`. Everything else involves "fiddling whilst Rome burns".

Comment: Don't initialize `x`, `y` and `z` in the constructor? Other than that, I agree with @DavidArno it looks like you're abusing Singletons as global variable containers.

Comment: Or you can just make it `Lazy`.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - no, not really.

Comment: @DavidArno - I take the point about the global variable usage but in this case `SomeWork()` just knows that `TheSingleton`'s properties need refreshing. It knows nothing about how to do that.
@Corak - where should they be initialized if not the ctor? the `Instance()` method doesn't know the context in which it is being called.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that state you're abusing the singleton pattern.

Unfortunately, the code example is incomplete, and so it's not possible to fully understand the scenario. But…

If the *only* thing in the singleton are those values that need to be refreshed, then clearly this object should *not* be a singleton at all. You should just require the caller to create a new instance any time it wants to "refresh".

If you made this a singleton because there *are* some things that are invariant and can/should be shared, then you still should not make the public object itself a singleton. Instead, use a singleton as part of the *implementation*; i.e. a `private static` member that manages the invariant parts, while individual instances contain the data that may need to be refreshed. In this design, you would again require the caller to create a new instance in order to "refresh".

Note that you could include a `Refresh()` method on a non-singleton implementation. However, I would advise against that. It unnecessarily would complicate the design of the API. Also, if you refrain from allowing a "refresh" on the object itself, you can make the object immutable, which has benefits if and when the code is ever used in a multithreaded scenario.

Comment: I think I get where you're going but I can't visualise a solution.  If I hid (e.g. via pimpl idiom) `TheSingleton`, what would I hide it in? - another singleton (visions of Matryoshka dolls arise)?  I basically have a lot of client classes that just need to be able to call `TheSingleton.Instance().GetStuff()` and so on.  And some client classes that need to be able to notify `TheSingleton` that it needs to refresh its data.  Makes me think of the Observer pattern.

Comment: Ideally, no other class will be specifically _telling_ a singleton to refresh itself. _Maybe_ it makes sense for the singleton itself to subscribe to some observable event (e.g. "observer pattern" as you note). Maybe it also makes sense for the singleton to expose an observable event so callers can be notified when it's been "refreshed". Unfortunately, your question is vaguely presented, so it's not possible to provide any specific answer along those lines.